# clear table data in a partial view on text box focusout event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, partial-views

I have a partial view (dynamic) which has a select list in one of the columns. I use Jquery to populate this list based on what is entered in a text box.

Anytime a user changes input in that text box, I want to clear the data from the table. Hence I tried the following options:

```
        $("#StudentTable tr>td").detach(); 
        $("#StudentTable tr>td").remove(); 
        $("#StudentTable tr>td").empty();
```

But I get an error:

```
'get(...).options' is null or not an object
```

on this line:

```
$("#TeachingAssistant").get(0).options.length = 0;
```

Here, "#TeachingAssistant" is the select list "id" in the partial view.

```
        <td>
            <select name="TeachingAssistant" id="TeachingAssistant"></select>
        </td>
```

I suppose it is deleting my the select list and hence not identifying it. How should I approach this? Any other way to clearing table data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#StudentTable tr td").html('');
```

will empty every td on your table, but if you have binded any events in any td content, you may have some problems!

to clear the select options you can use this:

```
$("#TeachingAssistant option").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following jquery code (ver 1.0) to delete the html inside table '#StudentTable':

```
$("#StudentTable").html("");
```

OR

```
$("#StudentTable").empty();
```

For reference you can visit link : [jQuery - html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

For geting the selected valus from dropdown use following code:

```
$("#TeachingAssistant").val();
```

For clearing:

```
$("#TeachingAssistant").val("");
```

For reference you can visit link : [jQuery - Get value](http://api.jquery.com/val/)